# Android actionbar background image не работает

Tags: android, xml, style, android-style

Не могу установить картинку на задний фон `ActionBar`. Содержимое файла `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <style name="BlackSkyBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="BlackSkyTheme" parent="BlackSkyBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/BlackSkyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BlackSkyTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/menu_background</item>
    </style> 

</resources>
```

В файле `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/BlackSkyTheme" >
```

Что я делаю не так? Картинка точно существует во всех папках `res\drawable-****\menu_background.png`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пропишите в коде:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.menu_background));
```

Comment: Вообще работает. А без помощи Java-кода никак? Просто у меня количество Activity около 10 будет. Как-то по нубски получается 10 раз один и тот же код в каждом файле прописывать.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте заменить ActionBar на Toolbar. Он прогрессивней, его легче настраивать и работать с ним.
Для этого нужно отключить ActionBar в стиле:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

и добавить Toolbar в вашу разметку:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
  android:background="@color/myColor">

   <Ваши самые смелые фантазии по наполнению - картинки, тексты и т.д. />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

соответственно support v7 должна быть включена (dependency в Graddle-файле)