# Как изменить цвет значка открывающего боковое меню

Tags: android, actionbar

На фото ниже указано какой значок имеется ввиду. Левый и желательно правый. Нужен белый цвет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сделал файл стиля style.xml для v21. В нем написано следующее:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/statusbar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSize_actionbar</item>
</style>
```

В программном коде при загрузке активити выполняется следующий код:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo4actionbar);
            }
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = activity.getWindow();
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.statusbar_background));
        }
    }
```

Таким способом включается этот самый пресловутый значок, убирается иконка приложения (на случай старых версий андроида), ну и меняется цвет статусбара.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для бутерброда:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowToggle</item>
</style>
<style name="DrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <!-- Ваш цвет -->
    <item name="color">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Для меню минимум 2 варианта, но думаю такой проще:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Overflow</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.OverFlow">
    <!-- Ваша иконка -->
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_image</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте Toolbar, как я уже предложил это [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498368/android-actionbar-background-image-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82/498393#498393)

он поддерживается с версии API 7+ и проще в использовании и настройке :)

Comment: Спасибо. Наверное со временем перейду на него, но с налету не получилось замениться на toolbar.