# Создание меню toolbar (три точки)

Tags: java, android, интерфейс

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать меню в виде трех точек в тулбаре. До этого создавал меню так:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Но это вызов через функциональную клавишу.
Также еще хотелось бы узнать как разместить иконку перед названием приложения в тулбаре? Спасибо.

**UPD**
Решение нашел в соответствии с [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498368/android-actionbar-background-image-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82) статьей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. В три точки (Overflow) убираются элементы меню со значениями `ifRoom/never` атрибута `app:showAsAction`. `ifRoom` элементы убирутся только если не поместятся в тулбар.
2. иконку ставить как-то так:

   ```
   toolbar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   ```

Comment: `app:showAsAction="never"` есть в пункте меню файла menu.xml и в предпросмотре файла menu.xml в студии есть эти три точки, а в предпросмотре `activity_main.xml` и в приложении нету... Использую тему `AppTheme` от `AppCompatActivity`. Может в теме какой то параметр отвечает за их отображение. По поводу тулбар, подскажи пожалуйста как его инициализировать, чтобы применить `toolbar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`.

Comment: @Pollux, если трёх точек нет то, видимо, у вас девайс с жесткой привязкой к хардверной кнопке меню. Тут можно использовать хак - поместить всё меню в `<tem>` с видимостью `always`, поставить ему иконку в 3 точки и внутрь уже пихнуть всё остальное. Иконку попробуйте ещё вот так: `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);` вместо тулбара. Или просто найдите его в разметке как любой другой виждет

Answer (score 2):

Проблема отображения в `ActionBar` 3-х точек на андроид устройствах у которых есть `hardware menu button` уже редко, но все же встречается.

Я для своего Samsung GT-i8552 применял в методе `onCreate()` следующую конструкцию:

```
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if (menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

Решение тогда нашел где-то на просторах en.SO.

**P.S.:**
Но все же потом перешел на Toolbar, хотя для старых версий андроид присутствовала проблема - не было тени под тулбаром на андроид ниже 5.0.

Так что дело вкуса.